# webpack copyFiles fails on symbolic folder

Tags: webpack

I have a Symfony project. I installed CKEditor using composer, and then

```
npm install -D ./vendor/myVendor/ckeditorPackage
```

to install the package. It creates a symbolic link to ensure webpack is always synced to composer.
I add

```
.copyFiles([
{from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/', to: 'ckeditor/[path][name].[ext]', pattern: /\.(js|css)$/, includeSubdirectories: false},
{from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/adapters', to: 'ckeditor/adapters/[path][name].[ext]'},
{from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/lang', to: 'ckeditor/lang/[path][name].[ext]'},
{from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/plugins', to: 'ckeditor/plugins/[path][name].[ext]'},
{from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/skins', to: 'ckeditor/skins/[path][name].[ext]'},
{from: './node_modules/ckeditor4/vendor', to: 'ckeditor/vendor/[path][name].[ext]'}
```

])

to webpack.config.js, but when building it fails with

```
   WARNING  The "from" option of copyFiles() should be set to an existing directory but "./node_modules/ckeditor4/" seems to be a file. Nothing will be copied for this copyFiles() config object.
```

because it is a symbolic link:

```
$ ls -l | grep cked
lrwxrwxrwx    1 user user    63 de jul.  29 13:00 ckeditor4 -> ../vendor/myVendor/ckeditorPackage
```

How can I configure webpack to "follow" symbolic links?

Comment: I checked and just the first copyFile (the one directly on symbolic folder) fails; if I remove the first line the error is gone (but this is not a solution because the files aren't copied)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i solved it with an command :

```
php hp bin/console ckeditor:install assets/ckeditor4
```

And change the copyFile to use assets inst